# How to Return Priorvalue of Stage pickist on Opportunity object if Stage=Closed Lost

Tags: formula

I am trying to record the "Furthest Stage" an Opportunity got to before it was Closed Lost. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a workflow rule inorder to achieve this .

The workflow rule will have entry criteria when opportunity is Closed Lost and you will need a field update with a formula as

```
PRIORVALUE(StageName)
```

If you want to make this field non editable make it read only on page layout .If you want to add further secuirty via API write a small validation that prevents users from editing it .

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a formula, so you'll need at least a workflow rule to accomplish your goal. Depending on your opportunity stage complexity, you might consider changing your stage picklist values and/or writing a trigger.

For example, as a workflow rule, you could do the following:

```
Trigger: On create and every edit
Formula: ISNEW() || Furthest_Stage__c < TEXT(StageName)
Immediate Actions: Field Update > Furthest Stage > Formula: TEXT(StageName)
```

Then, you could rename your stages as follows (as an example):

- 01 Prospecting
- 02 Qualification
- 03 Needs Analysis
- 04 Value Proposition
- 05 Id. Decision Makers
- 06 Perception Analysis
- 07 Proposal/Price Quote
- 08 Negotiation/Review
- 09 Closed Won
- 00 Closed Lost

Using lexicographic sorting, 00 will necessarily be less than all other values, so the workflow rule would update the field only if Furthest_Stage__c is less than the current stage. Note that Furthest_Stage__c is a simple text field.

Of course, make sure the field is set as read-only so that users cannot accidentally edit the value.